# Microsoft Endpoint Manager Error deploying Preference File to Supervised MacBook

Tags: macos, mdm, intune

When deploying a preference file (".plist") through MS Endpoint Manager ("Intune") to a supervised MacBook Pro I get a an error:

- Setting name: ConfigurationXmlPcl
- Error codes: -2016341103 and 0x87d11391

This is the preference file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>EnableMediaRouter</key>
        <false />
        <key>HomepageLocation</key>
        <string>https://somesubdomain.sharepoint.com</string>
        <key>NewTabPageSearchBox</key>
        <string>redirect</string>
        <key>PasswordManagerEnabled</key>
        <false />
        <key>PasswordProtectionChangePasswordURL</key>
        <string>https://passwordreset.somedomain.com</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Tried to search for the setting and the error codes, but could not find anything related to Intune.

Any push in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: have the same error. were you able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and error codes except trying to push Zoom configurations.

I was able to resolve this by stripping the all additional tags (, , etc) and leaving only values.  For example my edited .plist looked like this:

```xml
<key>ZAutoSSOLogin</key>
<false/>
<key>ZSSOHost</key>
<string>******.zoom.us</string>
```

Also I had the 'Preference domain name'/App ID wrong and had to correct it (had entered us.zoom.voice and the actual App ID for Zoom for Mac is us.zoom.xos.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How have you managed to define into your preference file the "PackageRecommand" settings with all the others.

I know that MS says to no include any dict bracket but i do not see any other ways to get all settings, and I followed the Zoom article.

For example, my preference file is looking as below

```
<dict>
    <key>nogoogle</key>
    <true/>
    <key>nofacebook</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NoSSO</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepSignedIn</key>
    <true/>
    <key>zAutoUpdate</key>
    <true/>
    <key>EnableSilentAutoUpdate</key>
    <true/>
    <key>AlwaysCheckLatestVersion</key>
    <true/>
    <key>disableDaemonInstall</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Login_Domain</key>
        <string>CorrectDomainName</string>
    <key>EnableMirrorEffect</key>
        <true/>     
    <key>PackageRecommend</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ZDisableVideo</key>
            <false/>
            <key>DisableComputerAudio</key>
            <false/>
            <key>MuteWhenLockScreen</key>
            <true/>         
            <key>ZAutoJoinVoip</key>
            <false/>
            <key>AudioAutoAdjust</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ZDualMonitorOn</key>
            <false/>
            <key>ZAutoFullScreenWhenViewShare</key>
            <false/>
            <key>ZAutoFitWhenViewShare</key>
            <true/>
            <key>zDisableAnnotation</key>
            <false/>
            <key>EnableDoNotDisturbInSharing</key>
            <true/>
            <key>DisableWhiteboard</key>
            <false/>            
            <key>EnableShareVideo</key>
            <true/>         
            <key>EnableShareAudio</key>
            <true/>         
            <key>FullScreenWhenJoin</key>
            <false/>            
            <key>AutoHideToolbar</key>
            <false/>            
            <key>ZUse720PByDefault</key>
            <false/>            
            <key>zRemoteControllAllApp</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ConfirmWhenLeave</key>
            <true/>
            <key>DisableScreenShare</key>
            <true/>
            <key>SetSuppressBackgroundNoiseLevel</key>
                <string>0</string>
        </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is looking for an answer.
Create the Configuration Profile as a Template and choose Preference File.
Edit all the .plist code out of the xml so you're just left with the:

```
<key>name</key>
<value/>
```

eg:

```
<key>BrowserSignin</key>
<integer>2</integer>
<key>DefaultSearchProviderEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>DefaultSearchProviderSearchURL</key>
<string>https://google.com/search?q={searchTerms}</string>
<key>ForceSync</key>
<true/>
<key>HideFirstRunExperience</key>
<true/>
<key>HubsSidebarEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

Then it'll deploy without the 0x87d11391 error.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, while using us.zoom.config.plist.

Deployed it using Intune -> macOS Configuration Profile -> Configuration settings -> Preference file

Preference domain name: us.zoom.xos

```
<key>NoGoogle</key>
<true/>
<key>NoFacebook</key>
<true/>
<key>zDisableVideo</key>
<true/>
<key>zAutoJoinVoip</key>
<true/>
<key>zDualMonitorOn</key>
<true/>
<key>zAutoFullScreenWhenViewShare</key>
<true/>
<key>zAutoFitWhenViewShare</key>
<true/>
<key>zUse720PByDefault</key>
<false/>
<key>zRemoteControlAllApp</key>
<true/>
<key>zAutoUpdate</key>
<true/>
```

[image]