# Pushing plist files with Intune on macOS is renaming the file

Tags: macos, plist, intune

I'm trying to deploy an app (zoom specifically) via Intune to our macOS clients. I used the intune app packager to create a LOB app out of the PKG file Zoom dispenses for IT purposes. I've confirmed this app installs fine. i'm also trying to push a plist file along with this app, so I've created a configuration profile in intune and targeted all devices with it.

When the plist file is getting uploaded, the Intune UI asks for a bundle ID. I entered "us.zoom.xos" as the bundle ID (same as my app that successfully deploys). After the configuration profile is deployed, I see some plist files get generated at "/Library/Managed Preferences" on the mac. However, when I launch the Zoom software, the preferences are not used.

I think there is an issue with format going on here, but i'm not sure. I had to strip my original plist of certain tags like in this post to avoid errors

[Intune plist deployment error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71588638/microsoft-endpoint-manager-error-deploying-preference-file-to-supervised-macbook/72205946#72205946)

It would seem that the Intune deployment process renames the plist file, and I suspect that is why Zoom cant read it. This documentation from Zoom states the file can be read from the "/Library/Managed Preferences" directory, but that the file also needs to be named "us.zoom.config.plist." manually renaming the file after it's deployed via intune allows the Zoom app to read it.

[Zoom macOS deployment guide](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115001799006-Mass-deploying-with-preconfigured-settings-for-macOS)

If you have any ideas how to get this file deployed via Intune and named correctly I'd appreciate the input!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself. I had to replace the Preference domain name\bundle ID in intune to name the plist file correctly on the endpoint. I changed the name from us.zoom.xos to us.zoom.config and Intune named the plist file file so the local Zoom app could read it.

The file is placed in "/Library/Managed Preferences" when pushed via intune config profile targeted to all devices.